Difference between a limaçon and lemniscate? Transforming between them
I'm interested if there's a perspective or visualization of both a limaçon and lemniscate simultaneously, i.e. when does one become the other and vice versa?  I understand they're both 'inverse' curves of a hyperbola, but is a limaçon exclusively the polar perspective of that inverse, in polar coordinates, and the lemniscate the Cartesian/equatorial perspective? The limaçon is apparently a 'polar curve,' but does that mean a lemniscate isn't?
In the images below, where the coordinate system isn't clear, the difference between the lemniscate (top) and limaçon (bottom) appears to be simply the size of the circle of inversion of the hyperbolæ correct? So could it be said the limaçon is simply a lemniscate that's been scaled up so much that one of its loops flips over to encircle the other? Or something like that?



More than the size, the position of the center of the circle (inside or outside the hyperbola) might be relevant.
